# Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: web-hosting

I'm using 000webhost for my app, it was working just fine until it started to show me this error constantly. I've tried changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` which didn't work, I've tried to put the link to the DB instead `mysql6.000webhost.com` which also didn't work. In the database configuration page it's mentioned that I should localhost as a DB host name, but that doesn't seem to work any more. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact 000webhost in order to get that information, as their setup may be unique.